# Value of variable to event listener

Tags: javascript

Task is simple, but my experience is not enough for solving it. I need to use outer variable in eventListiner. Now if i try to use outer variable, then i get "undefined". It seems this is solved by closures, but i can't fully understand how it works.

Wrong code:

```
function myfunc(){
    title = "Head";
    console.log(title);//Head
    document.getElementById("test").onclick = function(){
        console.log(title);//undefined
    }

}
```

Right code:

```
function myfunc(){
    title = "Head";
    console.log(title);//Head
    document.getElementById("test").onclick = function(){
        //some magic...
        console.log(title);//Head
    }

}
```

Hope for your help. Thanks.

---

Unfortunetly yours answers don't help. All this i have tryed, if it was that easy i would not write here. Still, I have made it yourself:

```
function myfunc(){
            function cls(it){
                return function(){
                    console.log(it);
                }
            }
            title = "head";
            document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click",cls(title), false);//head
    }
```

Thank you, atleast you tried to help, and for minuses thanks too.

Comment: Apart from the comment "some magic..." both code examples are the same. This is useless if you expect us to comment on the differences

Answer (score 0):

No need of magic.  Better have it globally.

```
title = "Head";
function myfunc(){        
    console.log(title);//Head
    document.getElementById("test").onclick = function(){  // you can't have like this
        console.log(title);//Head
    }    
}
```

Comment: It makes no difference if you declare `title` inside `myfunc`'s scope or not, as in both cases it was defined outside the click handler's scope. In fact, by defining it without using `var`, the variable is already added to the global window scope.

Comment: @DerekHenderson Thanks.  `document.getElementById("test").onclick = function(){` then this code might be the problem?

Comment: Exactly, the problem exists in the code described as `// some magic`, and without knowing what the magic is we have no way of helping.

Answer (score 0):

pull the title out of `myfunc()`:

```
var title = "Head";
function myfunc() {
  document.getElement...
}
```

Comment: It makes no difference if you declare `title` inside `myfunc`'s scope or not, as in both cases it was defined outside the click handler's scope. In fact, by defining it without using `var`, the variable is already added to the global window scope.

Comment: @DerekHenderson True. Overlooked the fact it was defined without var.